# Decidability of $SEQ_{CFG} = \{⟨G,H⟩ \mid \text{$G,H$ are CFGs and $L(G) ⊆ L(H)$}\}$

Tags: context-free, proof-techniques

How can I prove that $SEQ_{CFG} = \{⟨G,H⟩ \mid \text{$G,H$ are CFGs and $L(G) ⊆ L(H)$}\}$ is decidable ?

I know that $EQ_{CFG} = \{⟨G, H⟩ \mid \text{$G,H$ are CFGs and $L(G) = L(H)$}\}$ is not.

Comment: You cannot prove that it's decidable, since it's undecidable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to see that your problem is undecidable is by reduction from universality. It is known that one cannot decide whether $L(H) = \Sigma^*$. This is just your problem when $L(G) = \Sigma^*$.

Answer (score 4):

We also know that $L(G)=L(H)$ iff both $L(G)\subseteq L(H)$ and $L(H)\subseteq L(G)$.

Now assume $SEQ_{CFG}$ is decidable, then we can decide both ...

Comment: Do you know how to prove $SEQ_{CFG}$ ?